# Background fixo em HTML5 CSS3

Tags: html5, css3

Coloquei um background x no meu site, com o código css:

```
body
{
    background-image: url("../imagens/back.jpg");
    background-color: rgba(64, 118, 182, 1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
}
```

Queria que a imagem nao repetisse, mas que ficasse fixa na tela, quando o usuário rolasse o scroll não alteraria o fundo do site, o background continuasse no seu lugar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adicione:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[Veja este exemplo da W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment)

Comment: Deu certo, valeu